# AWS set date to midnight

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

What is the best way to initialize a Date to midnight using AWS AppSync utility.

I need to know if we have something like this

```
  var d =  (new Date()).setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)
```

By using  `$util.time.nowEpochSeconds()` , I am getting the epoch time but how do i identify the time difference that i need to add to set as midnight time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppSync doesn't offer that capability through utils only yet and this is good feedback, I'll make sure the team sees this.

In the meantime, as a workaround, you could modify the date string to achieve what you need.

```
#set($time = $util.time.nowFormatted("yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss/Z"))

#set ($split = $time.split("/"))
#set ($midnight = $split[0] + " 00:00:00" + $split[2])

time: $time
midnight: $midnight
midnight epoch seconds: $util.time.parseFormattedToEpochMilliSeconds($midnight, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ")
```

will print:

```
time: 2019-07-15/22:33:57/+0000
midnight: 2019-07-15 00:00:00+0000
midnight epoch seconds: 1563148800000
```

Comment: thank a lot, this solves my problem. Hopefully we will soon have this feature in AWS util .